# Maximum file size not recognised by PHP

Tags: php

I have this image upload PHP file. Everything seems to work except the maximum size (300k), as it accepts images of any size...

```
<?php
if((!empty($_FILES["ex1"])) && ($_FILES['ex1']['error'] == 0)) {

  $filename = basename($_FILES['ex1']['name']);

  $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);

  if (($ext == "jpg") || ($ext == "jpeg") || ($ext == "png") || ($ext == "gif") && ($_FILES["ex1"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["ex1"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["ex1"]["type"] == "image/gif") && 
    ($_FILES["ex1"]["size"] < 30000)) {

      $newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/../temp/'.time();

      if (!file_exists($newname)) {

          if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ex1']['tmp_name'],$newname.'.'.$ext))) {
           echo "Hecho! Guardada como: ".$newname;
        } else {
           echo "Error: Se produjo un problema durante la subida".$newname;
        }
      } else {
         echo "Error: El archivo ".$_FILES["ex1"]["name"]." ya existe";
      }
  } else {
     echo "Error: Tamaño máximo excedido (300kb) o formato erróneo (jpg, png, gif)";
  }
} else {
 echo "Error: No existe el archivo";
}
?>
```

Comment: you are missing some brackets in your checks.

Comment: Thank you. I am about to check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some brackets. The OR will override the AND, when one condition matches everything will be true.

Place brackets around the OR blocks, like this:

```
if (
    (
        ($ext == "jpg") || ($ext == "jpeg") || ($ext == "png") || ($ext == "gif") 
    ) && (
        ($_FILES["ex1"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["ex1"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["ex1"]["type"] == "image/gif") 
    ) && (
        ($_FILES["ex1"]["size"] < 30000)
    )
) {
```

(indented for better readability)

Also you're missing one zero in `30000` while checking file size.

> 300000 is equivalent to approximately 300KB.

So, change

```
$_FILES["ex1"]["size"] < 30000
```

to

```
$_FILES["ex1"]["size"] < 300000
```

Answer (score 1):

`&&` has a higher precedence than `||`, therefore `a || b && c` equals `a || (b && c)`.
You have:

```
($_FILES["ex1"]["type"] == "image/gif") && ($_FILES["ex1"]["size"] < 30000)
```

which means, than only GIF images must be smaller than 300KB.
Put brackets around your "or" groups:

```
if (
    (($ext == "jpg") || ($ext == "jpeg") || ($ext == "png") || ($ext == "gif")) &&
    (($_FILES["ex1"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["ex1"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["ex1"]["type"] == "image/gif")) &&
    ($_FILES["ex1"]["size"] < 30000)
   )
{
```

Answer (score 1):

Both Gerald and Siguza are right on what they say. However there's something I'd like to add.

The big, complex IF condition is heavily affecting the readability of your code. You'll be interested in doing something like this instead:

```
function handleUpload(){
    $maxFileSize = 30000;
    $allowedExtensions = array('jpg','jpeg','gif');

    if($_FILES["ex1"]["size"] > $maxFileSize){
        echo "File is too big";
        return false;
    }

    $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);

    if(!in_array($ext, $allowedExtensions)){
        echo "Extension not allowed";
        return false
    }
    // Handle upload
    return true;
}
```

The goal is to:
1-Return as soon as possible, which makes the code easier to read and to debug
2-Do not make complex structures, which makes the code easier to read and to debug
3-Allow comments on each block, and to output a more accurate message when the upload fails.

If you follow this structure you'll code much faster, easier and with less chances of making mistakes.

I hope this helps.